# Android java Finding a location and tapping there

Tags: java, android

So, I used this code

```
   public void loadLevel(float x, float y)
   {
      if(PopUpsGone == true)
      {
          if(x > 106 && x < 243 && y > 375 && y < 465)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           if(x > 7 && x < 215 && y > 83 && y < 245)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           if(x > 306 && x < 458 && y > 66 && y < 212)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "3",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
           if(x > 461 && x < 620 && y > 9 && y < 127)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "4",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
      }



   }
```

To tap at certain areas, when I did it on my emulator it worked perfect but when I did it on a different phone It wouldn't work or I would have to tap a bunch of times.

What's the best way to tap on a certain areas for different screens

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are taking screen density into account. Where you tap on one device may be a completely different coordinate on another device because they have different screen densities (there are more pixels per square inch).

Get the device density:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Then try multiplying the coordinates you are checking for by the density:

```
public void loadLevel(float x, float y)
{
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    x*=density;
    y*=density;
    ...
}
```

This should help taps to be more consistent from device to device.

Comment: Thank you! I shall try it and get back to you.

Comment: Yes. Try outputting the x,y coordinates as you move your finger on the screen. This should give you a better indicator as to what is different from device to device.

Comment: I have only worked with touch events in View classes. These classes can take advantage of an onTouch method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). With this method, you would take the event parameter, grab the x & y properties from it, and simply run a Log.d("", "x,y:" + x + ", " + y);